# how to get vendor id and product id of a plugged usb device on windows using vc++?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

How do I do this in VC++? All the answers I found here is done using Qt. And the other solutions mention how it is to be done in Linux. I need help in how it is to be done in windows using vc++. Please help.